# Looking for a way to "mark" emails from an exchange server

Tags: email, exchange

I'm trying to find a way to mark emails on an exchange server (2007), the same way (or similar) that you can mark with colors on your local emails.

I explain: we're 4 people in the world accessing the same mailboxes, and the goal is to know who's actually working out wich case.

Is there an extension, or some free solution allowing that?
The flaging is not enough, each person should become a color, or symbol.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: If you open the email, you can click "Options -> Edit Message" and then change the subject line. It's not coloured, but you could put "{yourname}..." at the start of the subject. It would also be easy to add macros to add/remove the text quickly.

Comment: Edit: you can change the subject line anyway, you only need to click "Edit Message" to change the body of the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looks like you guys could use some kind of CRM application to streamline your work.

There are a lot of options regarding CRM's. One i'm very familiar with is:
 - **[vTiger:](http://www.vtiger.com/)** is Open Source and have a nice Outlook plugin, for free as in beer.

You could assing each mail that you guys recieve to a case, then you can asigns several states to this cases.

or maybe you allready have one an you need an outlook plugin and i'm wasting your time and mine here.

Good luck bye.

Comment: The problem is that we work for NetApp, and they have very special policies regarding software implementations. Plugins for Outlook are not problematic, but new CRM... I don't really know if it's suitable.